# Shortest C code to display argv in-order

Tags: code-golf, tips, c

I recently tried to produce the shortest C code possible to display all its command line arguments (which are stored in argv).

I ended with a relatively small piece of code, and I was wondering if there was some trick I'm not aware of.
Here's my try (I compile with C17, but any standard before C23 is very likely to compile/link/run as intended, probably with some warnings though):

```c
main(c,v)int**v;{for(;*v;)puts(*v++);}
```

First, `main(c,v)int**v`. In C, every variable and function must have a type, but if it isn't specified at the declaration, then `int` [is assumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171602/what-is-the-default-type-for-c-const).
For now, it means `main` function returns an `int`, and both `c` and `v` (argc and argv) are also of `int` type. But, the `int**v` right after the closing parenthesis is actually changing the type of `v` to `int**`. This syntax is the old-style function definition, back from the K&R book. However, C23 standard plans to remove this feature from the language (see on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition)).
So we end up with `c` being an int (as a normal `argc` is), and `v` being an `int**` (contrary to a normal `argv` which is `char**` or `char*[]` (but `char*[]` is treated as a `char**` in a function)).

Then, the for loop `for(;*v;)` (note: a `while(*v)` does the same thing). As a remainder, `v` is filled with a list of char pointers to the command line arguments, but they're treated as integer pointers and not character pointers here. Thus, the loop runs until the first pointer in `v` is NULL (is equal to 0).

`puts(*v++);` does two things ; writing down the first string (it takes the first pointer in `v`, a `int*`, but `puts` expects a `char*`, so it can correctly deal with it) in the console and increases `v` (instead of having an iterator variable i, then doing `v[i]`, here I use `*v` and `v++` to save some characters). I also haven't used curly brackets around the for loop because when omitting them, the loop body is the first statement below it. I used `int` instead of `char` to declare `v`, in order to save a char. But is there a platform where those pointer types aren't the same size ? I once saw that function pointers may have a different size than ordinary pointers, but I don't know if this may be true for two pointers of different types.

It is guaranteed that `argv[argc]` is NULL, thus the code is guaranteed not to have an infinite loop (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772796/argvargc)).

Then no need to add a `return 0;` because it is guaranteed `main` will return 0 if I don't put a `return` statement.

Some may wonder why I was able to call `puts` without including stdio.h, it's because in C, [the whole library is linked to the binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199076/printf-and-scanf-work-without-stdio-h-why?noredirect=1&lq=1) (this question is a duplicate, but I put it here because the answer better explains this point than the original question). It also not seems to have a standard behavior (hence the warning), thus be aware of that (never rely on an undefined behavior). Same thing seems to apply for implicit `int` type.
Can someone confirm or not ?

Thus, my final question, is there any way to shorten this code ? I'm asking either for standard or platform-specific ways.

Sorry for the long post, but I wanted to explain for any interested beginner.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice question!

Comment: Thanks, glad you appreciate it !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 37 bytes

```c
main(c,v)int*v;{for(;*v;)puts(*v++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1mnTDMzr0SrzLo6Lb9IwxrI0CwoLSnW0CrT1ta0rv3//3/i/6R/yWk5ienF/3VzjY0A)

When using 32-bit, you can use `int` to store a pointer if not explicitly deferred

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 35 bytes, exit by segment fault

```c
main(c,v)int*v;{for(;puts(*v++););}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1mnTDMzr0SrzLo6Lb9Iw7qgtKRYQ6tMW1vTWtO69v///4n/k/4lp@Ukphf/1801NgIA)

Comment: Ok, I didn't think of using int as a pointer, thank you !
Even if I originally intended to exit properly (didn't mention it in the post), I like your second solution a lot.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 34 bytes

```c
main(c,v)int*v;{execvp("echo",v);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjeVchMz8zSSdco0M_NKtMqsq1MrUpPLCjSUUpMz8pWAwta1EJVQDTCNAA)

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org) with `-m32` flag, 28 bytes

*thanks to [@jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt)*

```c
main(c,v){execvp("echo",v);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1mnTLM6tSI1uaxAQyk1OSNfCShgXfv////E/0n/ktNyEtOL/@vmGhsBAA)

---

Replaces the current process image with the process image of `/bin/echo` (which is assumed to be in the `PATH`). It may not work correctly if the first argument(s) are recognized as flags by your version of echo.

May not be useful in every situation.

Note that more than the first argument could be messed up. For example, with GNU coreutils' echo:

- `-n`, `-e`, `-E` are recognized as short arguments, so `/bin/echo -n -e x` outputs just `x`, while `/bin/echo -n x -e` outputs `x -e`;
- `/bin/echo --help` and `/bin/echo --version` print a lot of stuff that wasn't present in the arguments.

Comment: Thanks, even if the first argument may be messed up, I still like your submission.

Comment: @Chi_Iroh You're welcome :) I added a note in the answer

Answer (score 2):

## [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) ([gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/)): 37 bytes

```c
main(c,v)int**v;{main(puts(*v),++v);}
```

Don't forget about recursion. :)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1mnTDMzr0RLq8y6GixQUFpSrKFVpqmjrV2maV37//9/w/9G/43/m/xLTstJTC/@r1sOAA)

Comment: Nice solution ! Even if it ends with a segmentation fault, this is very funny

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcoxCoAgGAbQuU5hm1oOaVunkR@sQCXSbJCu3leNDx4p8jYugOOyiOp46btuP3P6KeYbwW6RbzEzGhit9pCSFcFq23xVzO0NjNAwmB5y3i4J6oIKRr8) If it doesn't have to be a full program =)

Answer (score -1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 37 bytes

```c
main(c,v)int*v;{for(;*v;)puts(*v++);}
```

Comment: This is the exact same as [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267066/11490) that was posted 18 hours earlier. And this doesn't even have an explanation